# Span конвертировать в input и наоборот

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

Как конвертировать пример из [этой ссылки](https://dev.to/walternascimentobarroso/convert-span-to-input-and-vice-versa-using-javascript-nlh), написанный на js, в typescript, используя Angular.

Comment: [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)